# AWS Pipeline buildspec denied access to SecretManager, but deployed Beanstalk instance authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

We have set up a `MyReadOnlySecretServer` Policy as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:REGION:SOME_ID:secret:ID_OF_OUR_SECRET_JSON"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

We deploy a SpringBoot application on Elastic Beanstalk and have succeeded in retrieving and using the secret in production.

However, somehow, when we are still in the build phase of the pipeline, apparently our CodeStarWorker does not have access to reading the values. Here is the Exception:

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.SecretsManagerException:
>   User:
>   arn:aws:sts::SOME_ID:assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-blabla-ToolChain/AWSCodeBuild-some-long-id
>   is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on
>   resource:
>   arn:aws:secretsmanager:REGION:SOME_ID:secret:ID_OF_OUR_SECRET_JSON
>   (Service: SecretsManager, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
>   some-other-long-id)

We had had this Exception when trying to access the secrets while deployed, added the `MyReadOnlySecretServer` policy to the IAM Role `CodeStarWorker-blabla-ToolChain` as mentioned by the exception, and things were resolved.

Somehow, however, now that we try to run `mvn test` in the `buildspec.yml`, we get this very same Exception.

Why is it that our `buildspec.yml` is denied access despite being run by the same Code Pipeline that does the "source + build + deploy" stages? Once deployed, the instance has access, but while being built, it doesn't.

---

### Here is the `buildspec.yml` :

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
    commands:
      # Upgrade AWS CLI to the latest version
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
      - mvn clean compile test  # commenting this "test" makes it run properly
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn war:exploded
  post_build:
    commands:
      - cp -r .ebextensions/ target/ROOT/
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template-file template-export.yml
      # Do not remove this statement. This command is required for AWS CodeStar projects.
      # Update the AWS Partition, AWS Region, account ID and project ID in the project ARN on template-configuration.json file so AWS CloudFormation can tag project resources.
      - sed -i.bak 's/\$PARTITION\$/'${PARTITION}'/g;s/\$AWS_REGION\$/'${AWS_REGION}'/g;s/\$ACCOUNT_ID\$/'${ACCOUNT_ID}'/g;s/\$PROJECT_ID\$/'${PROJECT_ID}'/g' template-configuration.json
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - target/ROOT/**/*
    - .ebextensions/**/*
    - 'template-export.yml'
    - 'template-configuration.json'
```

Comment: Confirm that your CodePipeline is using the correct Service Role. Open the CodeBuild step, then click Edit > Environment. Ensure that the Service Role is pointing to the one you've configured.

Comment: @jpetty When I edit the Pipeline and click to edit the Build stage, none of the parameters are called "Environment". When I go into "Settings" of the Pipeline I see the `Service Role arn` with a link that points me to the IAM Role which indeed contains our `MyReadOnlySecretServer`. When I go in `CodeBuild > Build Projects > link_to_my_project_with_CodePipeline_as_source_provider > Build details > Environment > Service Role` there is a link that leads me to the same IAM Role that was linked in the `Service Role arn` of the CodePipeline Settings.

Comment: I'm now thinking maybe it'd be easier to reference to Secret Manager using the `env: secrets-manager:` in the `buildspec.yml` file, or through setting the `Environment Variables` in the `CodeBuild` settings, but in both cases I'm not sure how I'm supposed to reference properly to the Secret Manager's secret.

Comment: Tried with `env: secrets-manager:` and I get the same error during the build, but it crashed before everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that CodeBuild assumes the role 'CodeStarWorker-blabla-ToolChain' and the role itself does not have 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue' permission. Also, from memory, CodeStarWorker role has a permission boundary that may be blocking access even though you have explicitly added the required permission. A similar issue is discussed here:

- https://www.petefreitag.com/item/864.cfm

Comment: There is indeed a `permission boundary`, and it indeed does not contain any mention of `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`. I'll have to look into that and keep you updated.

Comment: I confirm: it was indeed the linked `Permissions Boundary` that was associated to the `CodeStar` project that was restricting the effective permissions of `CodeBuild`. I just edited the attached `Permissions Boundary` to `CodeStarWorker-blabla-ToolChain` and added the `"secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"` `Action` and also the appropriate `Resource` that was mentioned in the error (i.e. `arn:aws:secretsmanager:REGION:SOME_ID:secret:ID_OF_OUR_SECRET_JSON`). Thank you so much!